# jquery datatable sotring not working on this format "MMM-YYYY" in IE work fines in chrome

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have an issue in ie and edge data are not sorting as expected. i want to sort my data based on year. currently this works fine in google chrome as i want but not working in IE please check the snapshot. i have this string format "MMM-YYYY" column in jquery data table but this is not working in IE and edge. please help me

Here is my Code

```
 Grid
            .DataTable({
                data: Data,
                searching: false,
                paging: false,
                bInfo: false,
                serverSide: false,
                iDisplayLength: 100,
                processing: true,
                fnDrawCallback: function (oSettings) {

                },
                columns: [
                        { "name": "stringdate", "data": "Key", "searchable": false, },
                        { "name": "counter", "data": "Value", "searchable": false},
                ]
            }).order([0, 'desc'])
    .draw();
```

Comment: Please refer below link for type based sorting in datatable
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "monthYear", targets: 3 } //target refers column index
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: this sorting by month